# How to plot the predicted probability based on multilevel multinomial logit model in SAS?

Tags: plot, sas, predict, multi-level, mlogit

I want to plot the predicted age(including two age variations: age and age2), period and cohort variations in the sex disparities in job based on the following model, how should I add SAS codes?

```
proc glimmix data=model noitprint noclprint;                                                                                                      
  class period cohort job;                                                                                                              
  model job =age age2 sex syz edu_2 edu_3 party hukou mar diqu_2 diqu_3 diqu_4 fedu_2 fedu_3                                                                      
   / solution CL
  dist = mult link = glogit DDFM=BW ;                                                                        
  random intercept sex/sub=period group=job;                                                                      
  random intercept sex/sub=cohort group=job;                                         
  covtest GLM / WALD;
  NLOPTIONSTECHNIQUE=NRRIDG;                                                
run;
```

Thanks!